# Why are polygon transactions being dropped and replaced?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, evm, matic

It seems transactions on polygon can get automatically dropped and replaced.

original: 0xa67609bacf51ab83b1989e4097b4147574b4e26399bec636c4cfc5e12dfa2897
replaced: 0xec0d501619b5fc9cde6af41df929eeded252138a49965f15a7598bf2e532e555

What is happening here?

On Ethereum, I believe this can only happy if someone proactively replaces the tx by submitting another with the same nonce and higher gas price. Is that correct?

```
{"level":"error","message":"Error: transaction was replaced [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-TRANSACTION_REPLACED ] (cancelled=true, reason=\"replaced\", replacement={\"hash\":\"0xec0d501619b5fc9cde6af41df929eeded252138a49965f15a7598bf2e532e555\",\"type\":2,\"accessList\":[],\"blockHash\":\"0x252f663dfb64dd82dff77b5e4fbe2073cd77248c5ce8dff1191c87ac22d97cf9\",\"blockNumber\":39285028,\"transactionIndex\":60,\"confirmations\":2,\"from\":\"0x90Be1Ef5EEa48f1d33e2574a73E50D208bB3680E\",\"gasPrice\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x6cdbaaf8e5\"},\"maxPriorityFeePerGas\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x6cdbaaf8e5\"},\"maxFeePerGas\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x6cdbaaf8e5\"},\"gasLimit\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x0186a0\"},\"to\":\"0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174\",\"value\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x00\"},\"nonce\":112,\"data\":\"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\",\"r\":\"0x2503d5645a7620c94678ef0a5de4bca4e03b18943cec0511d58b7e444412b467\",\"s\":\"0x72c2cf739e2bfeb8335faab2c4b87b7b0464c9681a488456fa7c8fe25aef89c6\",\"v\":1,\"creates\":null,\"chainId\":137}, hash=\"0xa67609bacf51ab83b1989e4097b4147574b4e26399bec636c4cfc5e12dfa2897\", receipt={\"to\":\"0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174\",\"from\":\"0x90Be1Ef5EEa48f1d33e2574a73E50D208bB3680E\",\"contractAddress\":null,\"transactionIndex\":60,\"gasUsed\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x0110bc\"},\"logsBloom\":\"0x00000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000008000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000008000000800000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000180000010000000000001000000400000000000008000000000008000000000004000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000004000100002000000000081000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000008000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000\",\"blockHash\":\"0x252f663dfb64dd82dff77b5e4fbe2073cd77248c5ce8dff1191c87ac22d97cf9\",\"transactionHash\":\"0xec0d501619b5fc9cde6af41df929eeded252138a49965f15a7598bf2e532e555\",\"logs\":[{\"transactionIndex\":60,\"blockNumber\":39285028,\"transactionHash\":\"0xec0d501619b5fc9cde6af41df929eeded252138a49965f15a7598bf2e532e555\",\"address\":\"0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174\",\"topics\":[\"0x98de503528ee59b575ef0c0a2576a82497bfc029a5685b209e9ec333479b10a5\",\"0x00000000000000000000000090be1ef5eea48f1d33e2574a73e50d208bb3680e\",\"0xc726f5f957d29df36c915d2f2816a5906bdb096a68d79abeb83102359a3c51ef\"],\"data\":\"0x\",\"logIndex\":250,\"blockHash\":\"0x252f663dfb64dd82dff77b5e4fbe2073cd77248c5ce8dff1191c87ac22d97cf9\"},{\"transactionIndex\":60,\"blockNumber\":39285028,\"transactionHash\":\"0xec0d501619b5fc9cde6af41df929eeded252138a49965f15a7598bf2e532e555\",\"address\":\"0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174\",\"topics\":[\"0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef\",\"0x00000000000000000000000090be1ef5eea48f1d33e2574a73e50d208bb3680e\",\"0x00000000000000000000000090be1ef5eea48f1d33e2574a73e50d208bb3680e\"],\"data\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002710\",\"logIndex\":251,\"blockHash\":\"0x252f663dfb64dd82dff77b5e4fbe2073cd77248c5ce8dff1191c87ac22d97cf9\"},{\"transactionIndex\":60,\"blockNumber\":39285028,\"transactionHash\":\"0xec0d501619b5fc9cde6af41df929eeded252138a49965f15a7598bf2e532e555\",\"address\":\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010\",\"topics\":[\"0x4dfe1bbbcf077ddc3e01291eea2d5c70c2b422b415d95645b9adcfd678cb1d63\",\"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010\",\"0x00000000000000000000000090be1ef5eea48f1d33e2574a73e50d208bb3680e\",\"0x000000000000000000000000e7e2cb8c81c10ff191a73fe266788c9ce62ec754\"],\"data\":\"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080d77c3b67cb80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003005ebfb86a0d1350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ebfb8e3e34e504eca50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002ffdde83c2ea547d0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ebfb964baca8bb695d\",\"logIndex\":252,\"blockHash\":\"0x252f663dfb64dd82dff77b5e4fbe2073cd77248c5ce8dff1191c87ac22d97cf9\"}],\"blockNumber\":39285028,\"confirmations\":2,\"cumulativeGasUsed\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x8d88d1\"},\"effectiveGasPrice\":{\"type\":\"BigNumber\",\"hex\":\"0x6cdbaaf8e5\"},\"status\":1,\"type\":2,\"byzantium\":true}, code=TRANSACTION_REPLACED, version=providers/5.7.1)"}
```

Answer (score 1):

> *On Ethereum, I believe this can only happy if someone proactively replaces the tx by submitting another with the same nonce and higher gas price. Is that correct?*

Yes, and the same is possible on Polygon and other EVM chains.

Senders can replace their transactions for multiple reasons. For example, high-frequency trading bots continuously check if their pending transactions are still likely to be profitable - and if the transaction is not going to be profitable, the bot replaces it with another one. Either with new recalculated params that they expect to be profitable or simply with transaction from/to the same address so at least they don't lose any more funds than just the gas fees.

*Note: Once you send a transaction, it's impossible to drop it completely from the mempool. That's why it is sent back `to` the sender address.*

Or sometimes transactions are replaced by regular users that specified insufficient `gasPrice` and want to speed up the transaction by replacing the gas price with a higher value.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but what's happening here is that polygon network is automatically cancelling and replacing the transaction.

I think it's a feature to avoid stuck transactions. I don't believe Ethereum network does this, though.

Comment: @RonanMcGovern It's not cancelled by the network automatically without any prior action - it's the sender who broadcasts the replacing pending transaction, and the network reacts to it. See https://support.polygonscan.com/support/solutions/articles/69000794387-how-to-replace-a-pending-dropped-transaction for example ... The same is possible on Ethereum and other EVM chains.

Comment: Thanks for the followup Petr. Yeah, the thing is that I'm not myself re-submitting... unless ankr (our provider) is doing that for us.

I know how speeding up a transaction and cancelling a tx works like this - you overwrite with the same nonce. But here I'm simply submitting a tx (via ankr) and finding that - on occasion - it gets dropped and replaced without me doing anything.

Comment: @RonanMcGovern That's interesting. I don't have any experience with Ankr, so hopefully anyone else can add to this... Just an observation: The tx hash changes only if the any of the params change (for example `gasPrice`). When you hash the 100% same transaction object twice, it results in the same hash both times. See https://pastebin.com/Ybmh1pEE

Comment: Thanks, yeah apparently there are reorgs from time to time on polygon, I think this is the cause